# Assign editorfor value to radiobutton in mvc view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model

I have a scenario where i have 3 radio buttons two of them have default values and for the third one I want that it should be assigned the value of a textbox. How can I achieve this below is some of my code :

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <label style="padding-bottom:0.5em;font-size:1em">
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.LicenseValidityDuration, "0", new { style = "width:2em" })
      Never
    </label>
  </td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <label style="padding-bottom:0.5em;font-size:1em">
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.LicenseValidityDuration, "-1", new { style = "width:2em" })
      Always
    </label>
  </td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <label style="padding-bottom:0.5em;font-size:1em">
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.LicenseValidityDuration, model => model.LicenseValidityDuration, new { style = "width:2em" })
      Days Before Expiry
    </label>
  </td>
  <td>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LicenseValidityDuration)
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You would need to use javascript/jquery to update the `value` attribute of the radio button in the `change` event of the textbox

Comment: should the textbox still be binded with the same model ?

Comment: Does not seem any point binding the textbox - the `DefaultModelBinder` will bind to the first instance of a the form vaue with key = LicenseValidityDuration (from the selected radio button) and the second (from the textbox) will be ignored anyway. In addition your just creating invalid html (duplicate ID's)

Comment: actually i want to have just one property for LicenseValidityDuration to be reused for both radio buttons and text box is this ok , I mean is this a good  practice or not

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment. Just manually create the textbox (without a `name` attribute since there is no point posting back its value)  - or add a dummy property to your view model and bind to that. There is no point binding both the radio button group and the textbox to the same property since the value in the textbox will be ignored anyway

Comment: yes got it now let me try, thanks for the suggestion